# Como ter certeza que o post com curl chegou no outro servidor?

Tags: php, libcurl

Como eu posso ter certeza que um *post* chegou ao seu destino?

E como eu posso montar o código para que ele não tenha problema com servidores na hora de enviar o *post*?

**envia.php**

```
$id = "10";

$nome = "Nome";

$fone = "(99) 9999-9999";

//variável Array responsável por agrupar os dados a serem enviados
$dados = array("id"=>$id,"nome"=>$nome,"fone"=>$fone);       

//URL para onde vai ser enviado nosso POST
$url = "http://pt.stackoverflow.com";    

// Aqui inicio a função CURL

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $dados);

curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
```

**recebepost.php**

```
$recebeID = $_POST['id'];

$recebeNome = $_POST['nome'];

$recebeFone = $_POST['fone'];

//exibindo as variáveis recebidas através do POST externo

echo "ID: ".$recebeID." - Nome: ".$recebeNome." - Fone: ".$recebeFone;
```

Comment: É só fazeres um `curl` de resposta que funciona da mesma forma só que no sentido contrário.

Comment: vc esta falando em colocar um curl na pagina "recebepost.php" para que ele envie uma resposta automática assim que o post chegar?

Comment: Sim é uma das opções.

Comment: Mas quando o curl chega no outro servidor ele recebe uma resposta, se essa resposta voltou então ele chegou com certeza

Comment: Entendi. O meu chefe quer um sistema igual o retorno automático do pagseguro e PayPal. Mas vejo no fórum dessas empresas a galera reclamando que o post não chegou, Aí surge uma grande duvida. Eu posso encontrar algum problema para enviar o post para algum servidor ou esses erros relatados são causados pelos próprios usuários que colocam a variável post em uma pagina e cadastram outra?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vou deixar abaixo uma função onde tem umas explicações e creio que irá lhe ajudar com essa questão. Ela não é uma função pronta para uso (copiar, colar e sair usando para todos casos), visto que você irá precisar modificá-la de acordo com as suas necessidades obviamente, porém já serve como uma boa base para entender melhor o funcionamento de como detectar se a requisição **POST** foi feita de maneira correta e a saída é válida.

Eu geralmente prefiro que a saída esteja em **JSON** e eu costumo definir sempre que a requisição tenha um parâmetro/key de nome "**status**" onde seu valor padrão seja **SUCCESS** e qualquer outro valor é definido como falha, e também uso um parâmetro/chave de nome "**msg**" onde é informado (para casos de erro) o tipo de erro: falha na autenticação, dados incompletos, dados em formato desconhecido e/ou inválido, etc...

```
<?php

/**
 * Passa a URL e os parâmetros pela função
 * Para retorno do corpo de resposta, use o parâmetro de referência $body
 * Para retorno de possível erro, use o parâmetro de referência $errormsg
 * A função retorna true em caso de sucesso e false em caso de falha
 * A falha ocorre se as funções do CURL retornarem valores que signifiquem falha
 * A falha também ocorre de acordo com as suas necessidades na validação da resposta
 * Por exemplo (Aplique de acordo com as suas necessidades):
 * 
 * Se a saída for vazia
 * Se a saída tiver um padrão e através de expressão regular retornar falso
 * Se a saída estiver em JSON e obrigatoriamente precisa que exista um parâmetro "status"
 * Se a saída estiver sm JSON e o parâmetro "status" seja diferente de "SUCCESS"
 * 
 * A função abaixo é apenas uma demonstração de como saber se algo deu certo ou não
 * Modifique de acordo com as suas necessidades
 */

function curl_post_42252( $url, $params = array(), &$body = null, &$errormsg = null ) {

    $fields = http_build_query( $params, '', '&' );

    set_time_limit(60);

    $ch = curl_init();

    $options = array(
        CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 30,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING       => '',
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => false,
        CURLOPT_HEADER         => true,
        CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS     => false,
        CURLOPT_POST           => true,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS     => $fields,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 60,
        CURLOPT_URL            => $url,
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:32.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/32.0',
        CURLOPT_VERBOSE        => true,
    );

    curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options );

    $exec  = curl_exec( $ch );
    $info  = curl_getinfo( $ch );
    $head  = substr( $exec, 0, $info['header_size'] );
    $body  = substr( $exec, $info['header_size'] );
    $error = curl_error( $ch );
    $errno = curl_errno( $ch );

    curl_close( $ch );

    /**
     * Início das verificações para saber se a requisição foi feita corretamente
     */

    /**
     * Exec retornou falso?
     */

    if ( $exec === false ) {
        $errormsg = 'curl_exec';
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Tem algum erro?
     */

    if ( $error !== '' ) {
        $errormsg = 'curl_error';
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Tem algum erro? (Redundante)
     */

    if ( $errno ) {
        $errormsg = 'curl_errno';
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * A parte acima verifica se não houve erros nas funções do CURL (HTTPS, Timeout, etc...)
     * Daqui para baixo estão os exemplos de como validar e saber se realmente a resposta de saída é válida
     * Usando expressão regular ou JSON
     * Adapte de acordo com as suas necessidades
     */

    return true;

    /**
     * Código HTTP de resposta é diferente de 200? Geralmente o código HTTP de resposta é 200
     */

    if ( $info['http_code'] !== 200 ) {
        $errormsg = 'curl_http_code';
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Corpo (resposta) (html/json/xml) é vazio? Geralmente há uma saída em JSON ou com algum valor simples informando falha ou sucesso
     */

    if ( trim( $body ) === '' ) {
        $errormsg = 'curl_body_empty';
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Validação por expressão regular (Exemplo fictício)
     */

    $pattern = '/ID\:/';

    if ( !preg_match( $pattern, $body ) ) {
        $errormsg = 'pattern_dont_match';
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Validação por valor JSON, supondo que a resposta esteja formatada em JSON e possua a chave "status" com o valor "SUCCESS" ou "ERROR" para Sucesso ou Erro
     */

    if ( ( $json = json_decode( $body ) ) === false || $json === null ) {
        $errormsg = 'json_decode_error';
        return false;
    }

    if ( !isset( $json->status ) ) {
        $errormsg = 'json_status_undefined';
        return false;
    }

    if ( $json->status !== 'SUCCESS' ) {
        $errormsg = 'json_status_fail';
        return false;
    }

    return true;

}

$url = 'http://pt.stackoverflow.com';

$parametros = array(
    'id'   => 'valor_id',
    'nome' => 'valor_nome',
    'fone' => 'valor_fone',
);

if ( !curl_post_42252( $url, $parametros, $resposta, $erro ) ) {
    echo $erro;
    die();
}

echo 'Successo<br/><br/>';
echo '<pre>';
var_dump( $erro );
var_dump( $resposta );
echo '</pre>';
die();

?>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado amigo.